# Will nested FastAPI REST API call via requests slow down the performance?

Tags: docker, python-requests, nested, benchmarking, fastapi

API 1 in container 1 --> API 2 in container 2

I have a simple FastAPI REST API (API 1) in one docker container invokes another simple FastAPI REST API (API 2) in another docker container. The call is via requests package.

When I perform Apache Benchmark test on API 2 (ab -n 10000 -c 500 http://[url of API 2]) , the (RPS) request per second is around 4600. However, when I perform the the same apache benchmark on API 1 (ab -n 10000 -c 500 http://[url of API 1]), the RPS drops to around 1350 despite API 1 is just a simple requests.post call to API2 without any processing logic. I do not understand why the nested call reduce the RPS so drastically

API 0 in container 0 --> API 1 in container 1 --> API 2 in container 2

To further confirm my observation, I created another FastAPI REST API 0 in another docker container which consists of a simple request.post call to API 1. The apache benchmark test (ab -n 10000 -c 500 http://[url of API 0]) further slowing down to RPS 530

May I know the reason? I thought http request call to FastAPI REST API shouldn't add that much overhead in the series of nested call

In my Microservice distributed application, I have multiple Microservice hosted in different containers whereby some processing of request from client browser might incur nested calls between microservices(for example, client browser call A, A call B, B call C)

Comment: Additional info -- the FastAPI REST API in each container (Alpine) is powered by Gunicorn running uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker workers. The reason I host the REST API in different docker containers is to mimic the pods in K8s. As eventually I would like to run this on K8s

Answer (score 0):

In absolute terms, if your container stack is handling 530 requests per second, then each request takes 1.9 ms.  That's pretty good on the whole.  (The performance problems I worry about in my day job are individual HTTP requests that take *minutes* to complete.)  I would not worry about tuning this.

It might be more interesting to break this down in terms of latency (time per request) rather than throughput (requests per unit time).  Apachebench can probably output median and 99th-percentile latency.  Just looking at averages, though:

| Path | Throughput | Average Latency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| api2 | 4600 req/s | 217 µs |
| api1 → api2 | 1350 req/s | 740 µs |
| api0 → api1 → api2 | 530 req/s | 1886 µs |

217 µs is quite fast; adding 0.5-1.0 ms for an additional HTTP hop seems reasonable to me.  Remember that Python is an interpreted language, so this setup will probably be slower than a compiled language like Go, if you're counting microseconds; but also that your "real" application will probably involve a database, and in most cases an SQL request will immediately dwarf these numbers.  If the database round-trip requires a minimum of 100 ms then adding 1 ms for an HTTP proxy hop is essentially free.

In the microservice environment you describe, having a sequence of cross-service calls is pretty typical.  I'd suggest tuning each service individually: if service B calls service C twice, and service C requires 500 ms to process a request, then the entire stack will require > 1s to run, but profiling service C on its own will hopefully point at the problem.  In my experience the most likely thing you'll need to focus on is the database setup.  Having fewer network hops is "better" in the abstract, but the numbers you show here suggest that adding or removing a proxy isn't going to be a big difference in the final performance.